# apache logs -0700]

Tags: apache, logging

I am looking at the apache logs of one of my websites.

The timestamp is registered like this:

```
[20/Oct/2011:03:22:43 -0700]
[20/Oct/2011:03:22:41 -0700]
[20/Oct/2011:03:22:41 -0700]
```

Can somebody tell me what -0700 is for ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a timezone. Specifically it's PST - pacific time in the US.

It means those times are in local time for PST. Sometimes logfiles output in UTC (AKA GMT), in which case it would say 0000.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the timezone, i.e. GMT -7 hours